# Replace keywords in an argument - bash scripting

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file that is taking in a path as an argument:

```
./<filename> /path/to/file...
```

What I want to do is replace the /path/to/... part with /another/file/...

I was trying to sed the argument in the following manner:

```
CUR_PATH=$1
OLD_PATH="\/path\/to\/"
NEW_PATH="\/another\/file\/"
sed "s/$OLD_PATH/$NEW_PATH/" $CUR_PATH
```

But this isn't working because of the fact that sed is trying to actually modify the file at CUR_PATH and not the actual statement of CUR_PATH. How do I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possibility is to use a here string:

```
CUR_PATH=$1
OLD_PATH="/path/to/"
NEW_PATH="/another/file/"
sed "s|$OLD_PATH|$NEW_PATH|" <<< $CUR_PATH
```

Also note that you can vary the delimiters for the substitution in sed, so that you don't have to escape the slashes in your path variables.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `sed`. `bash` a built-in substitution for variables. You can use:

```
NEW_PATH=${OLD_PATH/\/path\/to\//\/another\/file\/}
```

Note the backslashing of the `/`, because the expression is `${variable/old/new}`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use bash's substitution as Diego suggests, but for this particular case it is probably cleaner to do:

```
NEW_PATH="/another/file/${OLD_PATH##*/}"
```

which will replace the entire leading path of OLD_PATH with the string "/another/file/".  Note that the double quotes are only necessary if OLD_PATH may contain whitespace.

If you do want to use sed, you can simply echo OLD_PATH into a pipe.  And, when using sed for manipulating filenames, it is convenient to use a different separator.  For example:

```
NEW_PATH=$( echo $OLD_PATH | sed s@/path/to/my@/another/file@ )
```

Comment: The first method you posted isn't working quite like I intended it to. It's replacing the entire path up until the filename with the path I want. All I want it to do is replace the first two portions of the path with a different two. 
So, if I had /a/b/c/d and I want to change /a/b/ to /x/y/ it should end up like /x/y/c/d/ not /x/y/d...

Comment: You can reduce the replacement: `NEW_PATH=/x/y${OLD_PATH##/a/b}`